# Apiary multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, post, multipartform-data, blueprint, apiary

I have tried creating an Apiary request with multipart/form-data, which seems alright, except when I try actually sending it via the console on Apiary to an existing (and functional) endpoint written in Node.js using async-busboy I'm getting back

```
{
  "message": "Unexpected end of multipart data"
}
```

The Apiary Blueprint for this request looks like this:

```
+ Request

    + Headers

            Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY

    + Body

            --BOUNDARY
            Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"

            John Doe
            --BOUNDARY
            Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

            john.doe@email.com
            --BOUNDARY--
```

I'd like to know if there is any problem that can be fixed in the Blueprint snippet or if this is even supported, or if the problem might be in the server itself (but the server works when I send a multipart post request from postman, curl and there are also few client implementations using it)

Comment: It could be that your `Body`'s lines end with LF (`\n`) instead of CRLF (`\r\n`). The spec says that line endings must be CRLF.

Comment: It seems like that actually is the problem. But is there a way how to fix that in Apiary?